# how to set pdf in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

my error :

NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values
at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure

my location

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'mpdf';
$rendererLibraryPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/PHPExcel/Tests/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;
```

my name file mpdf.php on htdocs/PHPExcel/Tests/PDF/'

how can i fixed??
if i add

```
 $randererLibrary = 'mpdf.php';
```

then its create a pdf but the pdf in corrupted.
Many thanks.

Comment: Likely the problem is that value in `$renderedLibraryPath` isn't correct. Print it out and make sure it lines up directly with your server's file structure.

Comment: if i echo the path then it show H:/xampp/htdocs/PHPExcel/Tests/PDF/mPDF @Micholas Pickering

Comment: Is that path correct on your server? climb it from the bottom up.

Comment: yes its correct @NicholasPickering

Answer (score 0):

Define your rendered library path like this

```
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPExcel/Tests/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;
```

you need to use full path.